# It will be a blast when he arrives

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence correct? If it's not, then please explain why.

> "When he arrives it will be a blast"

Let's assume that the context is as following - there are two people waiting for the third. While waiting the first says to the other a sentence which is above. If i've made a mistake writing this, please correct that as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Either ordering is syntactically/semantically "correct".  The title ordering is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "a blast" is informal and means "a good time". English speakers tend to be less picky over informal language, but technically the use of the pronoun "it" must refer to something previously stated, and in your sentence that can only be the *arrival*, so you are saying *his arrival* will be enjoyable and I do not think that is what is intended. I think you mean to say that you will have a good time with this person *after* he arrives. Therefore I think the informal phrase should be:

> When he arrives *we will have a blast*.

Check out this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=be%20a%20blast%2Chave%20a%20blast&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbe%20a%20blast%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20blast%3B%2Cc0) to see how much more "have a blast" is used over "be a blast".

Answer (score 0):

This verbal phrase (**to be a blast**) means the following: *to be very enjoyable and exciting* (LDOCE, 5th version). This is mostly used in America and its usage is informal. Nonetheless, your sentence is grammatically correct. Consider the following expressions if you'd like to replace your one with any of these (it's of course not obligatory):

- to be good company
- to be good/great/a lot of fun
- to be a good laugh